# Linux control a running vlc process through command line

Tags: bash, ubuntu, vlc

is there any way to control an already running VLC player on ubuntu. 
For example, i am trying to start a vlc video full screen with a default audio.

and then control the volume and other features through netcat or some other command remotely. is it possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you looked at the rc (remote control) interface ? It controls a VLC process via a Unix Domain Socket. See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200203114903/https://getluky.net/2006/04/19/vlcs-awesome-rc-interface/) and [here](http://n0tablog.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/controlling-vlc-via-rc-remote-control-interface-using-a-unix-domain-socket-and-no-programming/) for more info.

Comment: Always bring the relevant information into your answer because links break. As your (first one) has and your second one eventually will too.

Answer (score 12):

The script [`player control`](https://gist.github.com/exic/1d051e3a15f61e06caf4) from [exic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27249039) is just a wrapper for some `dbus` commands.
To use them without the script, try the following:

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause
```

The last `PlayPause` can be replaced with, e.g., `Play`, `Pause`, `Previous`, `Next`.

If you have `qdbus` installed, it can be used as an alternative to `dbus-send`:

```
qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause
```

A list of all available calls can be obtained by leaving out the last argument:

```
qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2
```

Comment: It seems that setting the volume with `qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Volume 0.5` always sets the volume to `0` due to a bug, though.

Comment: Easy, simple and usable.

Answer (score 4):

If you enable the HTTP remote interface on VLC, you can control VLC remotely with a web browser, or even an app on your phone.

With the HTTP interface enabled, you can also use wget or curl commands to send commands.

For example, enable VLC's HTTP interface (default port: 8080) with "password" for a password.  Then you can issue curl commands, either remotely or locally:

#### Curl Prefix

For brevity I will show the first part of the curl command here (the IP will most likely be your localhost, but the `8080` port is the default:

```
 curl -s -o /dev/null -u :password http://192.168.1.11:8080
```

then combine with the actions:

To pause:

```
.../requests/status.xml?command=pl_pause
```

To play:

```
.../requests/status.xml?command=pl_play
```

To play a specific playlist entry number:

```
.../requests/status.xml?command=pl_play&id=22
```

To change volume:

```
.../requests/status.xml?command=volume&val=133
```

Other command info: https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HTTP_requests/

Answer (score 2):

I'm controlling it remotely using dbus. VLC has implemented the MPRIS2 specification:

- [Control player](https://gist.github.com/exic/1d051e3a15f61e06caf4) (e. g. run `player-control vlc toggle`)
- [Get current status](https://gist.github.com/exic/2e88d1410432af0d43bd) (with argument `vlc`)