# How to close VLC gracefully using C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, vlc

I am running a surveillance system, and wanting to record the video from some CCTV cameras to my PC.

I can get the recording to occur using the VLC command line like this,

```
vlc rtsp://*username*:*password*@192.168.1.60:554/ch01/0  --qt-start-minimized --sout=#transcode{ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:file{dst=D:\CCTV\Concord\2019_05_24\2019-05-24_2111_C1.mp4,no-overwrite}
```

However I want to stop and restart the recording every half an hour so that I get files small enough that I can use.

I wrote a C# application to do this, it simply kills all VLC processes and starts new ones. It is triggered by task scheduler on the half hour.

This works when I run normal VLC instances showing in the taskbar. However I want they to be out of the way in the system tray. I can do this by adding this VLC option,

```
--qt-start-minimized
```

Which runs it under background processes if I look in task manager.

My code does this,

```
foreach(Process process in Process.GetProcesses().Where(x => x.ProcessName == "vlc"))
{
    Process.GetProcessById(id).CloseMainWindow();
}
```

However VLC no longer has a main window, so that doesn't work.

If I do this,

```
Process.GetProcessById(id).Kill();
```

The videos get corrupted because VLC doesn't exist gracefully.

I tried the other methods Close, Dispose, but they don't work.

It seems to me that I need to maximise these windows first before calling CloseMainWindow, or find some other way to exit them, or if there is an option in VLC to start a new file every half an hour?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Gracefully" killing a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411982/gracefully-killing-a-process)

Comment: That would suggest I need to maximise the window out of the system tray first. How can I do that?

Comment: I found this to maximise an application. But it didn't quite work. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2976/Detect-if-another-process-is-running-and-bring-it

Comment: @peter this blog describes how to stop the recording automatically after x seconds, and he complains about issues as well, but his might help https://blog.sourcefabric.org/en/news/blog/2077/Schedule-stream-recordings-from-the-command-line-Part-2.htm. The here https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=73132 they suggest to use rc interface to be able to send commands to vlc after it has started.

Comment: Why not sending message `WM_CLOSE` to its main window?

Comment: There is no main window because it is minimised to the system tray. If there is a way of maximising first that would work, but I have not found that yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try invoking vlc commands using RC (Remote command) Interface.
Documentation can be found here: https://wiki.videolan.org/documentation:modules/rc/
If you start vlc with the remote commands you can then send via websocked a command to stop the recording or close vlc.

Try adding to your command

> --intf rc --rc-host="my-ip:my-port" --rc-quiet --rc-extend

The list of available commands are:

```
longhelp
+----[ Remote control commands ]
|
| add XYZ  . . . . . . . . . . . . add XYZ to playlist
| enqueue XYZ  . . . . . . . . . queue XYZ to playlist
| playlist . . . . .  show items currently in playlist
| play . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . play stream
| stop . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . stop stream
| next . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  next playlist item
| prev . . . . . . . . . . . .  previous playlist item
| goto . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  goto item at index
| repeat [on|off] . . . .  toggle playlist item repeat
| loop [on|off] . . . . . . . . . toggle playlist loop
| random [on|off] . . . . . . .  toggle random jumping
| clear . . . . . . . . . . . . . . clear the playlist
| status . . . . . . . . . . . current playlist status
| title [X]  . . . . . . set/get title in current item
| title_n  . . . . . . . .  next title in current item
| title_p  . . . . . .  previous title in current item
| chapter [X]  . . . . set/get chapter in current item
| chapter_n  . . . . . .  next chapter in current item
| chapter_p  . . . .  previous chapter in current item
|
| seek X . . . seek in seconds, for instance `seek 12'
| pause  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  toggle pause
| fastforward  . . . . . . . .  .  set to maximum rate
| rewind  . . . . . . . . . . . .  set to minimum rate
| faster . . . . . . . . . .  faster playing of stream
| slower . . . . . . . . . .  slower playing of stream
| normal . . . . . . . . . .  normal playing of stream
| f [on|off] . . . . . . . . . . . . toggle fullscreen
| info . . . . .  information about the current stream
| stats  . . . . . . . .  show statistical information
| get_time . . seconds elapsed since stream's beginning
| is_playing . . . .  1 if a stream plays, 0 otherwise
| get_title . . . . .  the title of the current stream
| get_length . . . .  the length of the current stream
|
| volume [X] . . . . . . . . . .  set/get audio volume
| volup [X]  . . . . . . .  raise audio volume X steps
| voldown [X]  . . . . . .  lower audio volume X steps
| adev [X] . . . . . . . . . . .  set/get audio device
| achan [X]. . . . . . . . . .  set/get audio channels
| atrack [X] . . . . . . . . . . . set/get audio track
| vtrack [X] . . . . . . . . . . . set/get video track
| vratio [X]  . . . . . . . set/get video aspect ratio
| vcrop [X]  . . . . . . . . . . .  set/get video crop
| vzoom [X]  . . . . . . . . . . .  set/get video zoom
| snapshot . . . . . . . . . . . . take video snapshot
| strack [X] . . . . . . . . . set/get subtitles track
| key [hotkey name] . . . . . .  simulate hotkey press
| menu . . [on|off|up|down|left|right|select] use menu
|
| @name marq-marquee  STRING  . . overlay STRING in video
| @name marq-x X . . . . . . . . . . . .offset from left
| @name marq-y Y . . . . . . . . . . . . offset from top
| @name marq-position #. . .  .relative position control
| @name marq-color # . . . . . . . . . . font color, RGB
| @name marq-opacity # . . . . . . . . . . . . . opacity
| @name marq-timeout T. . . . . . . . . . timeout, in ms
| @name marq-size # . . . . . . . . font size, in pixels
|
| @name logo-file STRING . . .the overlay file path/name
| @name logo-x X . . . . . . . . . . . .offset from left
| @name logo-y Y . . . . . . . . . . . . offset from top
| @name logo-position #. . . . . . . . relative position
| @name logo-transparency #. . . . . . . . .transparency
|
| @name mosaic-alpha # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . alpha
| @name mosaic-height #. . . . . . . . . . . . . .height
| @name mosaic-width # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . width
| @name mosaic-xoffset # . . . .top left corner position
| @name mosaic-yoffset # . . . .top left corner position
| @name mosaic-offsets x,y(,x,y)*. . . . list of offsets
| @name mosaic-align 0..2,4..6,8..10. . .mosaic alignment
| @name mosaic-vborder # . . . . . . . . vertical border
| @name mosaic-hborder # . . . . . . . horizontal border
| @name mosaic-position {0=auto,1=fixed} . . . .position
| @name mosaic-rows #. . . . . . . . . . .number of rows
| @name mosaic-cols #. . . . . . . . . . .number of cols
| @name mosaic-order id(,id)* . . . . order of pictures
| @name mosaic-keep-aspect-ratio {0,1} . . .aspect ratio
|
| help . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . this help message
| longhelp . . . . . . . . . . . a longer help message
| logout . . . . . . .  exit (if in socket connection)
| quit . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  quit vlc
|
+----[ end of help ]
```

This question is similar to yours, and this specific answer explains why CTRLC is not the right way to close: [VLC screen capture using terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084098/vlc-screen-capture-using-terminal).

Example usage: http://sureskumar.com/RemoteVLC/#examples (Arduino code but easy to understand)

Comment: This works a treat. Will add below my final solution.

Answer (score 0):

*"Kill is the only way to terminate processes that do not have graphical interfaces."*

So basically, the only chance you have to make this work is to check if VLC process offers **a way to control it while running in background**: in this way, you could **first stop the recording process** and **then kill the process**.

I'm not aware of what functionalities it exposes, but You could do that with [VLC HTTP interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49185496/2795679) or maybe check for some `dbus` commands?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Norcino, your solution works well. I added in the options you mentioned,

```
-I rc --rc-host=192.168.1.4:10001 --rc-quiet
```

Then my C# looks like this,

```
KillSingleInstance(10001);

public void KillSingleInstance(int port)
{
    List<byte> ip = new List<byte>();

    ip.Add(192);
    ip.Add(168);
    ip.Add(1);
    ip.Add(4);

    IPAddress ipAddress = new IPAddress(ip.ToArray());
    IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

    Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,  
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); 

    sender.Connect(remoteEP);

    byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("quit\n"); 

    sender.Send(msg);

    sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);  
    sender.Close();
}
```

The VLC instances are completely running in the background.

Plus it has a try and catch block etc. Will do more testing, but so far works well.